# In SQL, how can I divide a value by the number of rows it is in?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am selecting from two tables, a product table and a shipping table, and building the table below, but I'd like to divide the product $ value by the number of rows per ID so that the product $ is split between all the rows it appears on. Is there a way to do this in the select statement as I'm building the table?

What I have:

```
  ID   |  Product $ | Shipping $
---------------------------------
123456 |  200.00    |  5.00
123456 |  200.00    | 10.00
123567 |  186.00    |  7.99
```

What I'd like:

```
  ID   |  Product $ | Shipping $
---------------------------------
123456 |  100.00    |  5.00
123456 |  100.00    | 10.00
123567 |  186.00    |  7.99
```

Comment: Average won't work since the average of $200 and $200 is still $200.

Comment: I was running into issues with the sub-queries, so I went the approach of calculating the count of multiples in a temp table beforehand and that when building my table above. Thanks for all the help, everyone.

Comment: This is an ideal case for learning how windowing functions work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler to use [windowing functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) instead of subqueries:

```
SELECT
  [ID]
 ,[Product $] / COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [ID])
 ,[Shipping $]
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,
([Product $]/(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM t t1 WHERE t1.id=t.id)) [Product $] ,
[Shipping $]
FROM t
```

Answer (score 1):

Before joining product & shipping table, you can calculate product price based on the count (as in the inner query) and then you can inner join it with shipping table. From the post-view, you can use the following query as a reference:

```
SELECT ps.id
    ,t1.new_c
    ,ps.shipping
FROM product_shipping ps
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id
        ,product / count(1) new_c
    FROM product_shipping
    GROUP BY id
        ,product
    ) t1 ON ps.id = t1.id;
```

Since sqlfiddle is down, Here you go with [ideone](http://ideone.com/huESPk)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, ([Product $] / (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TABLE t2 WHERE t2.ID = TABLE.ID)) as [Product $], [Shipping $]
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Average won't work since the average of $200 and $200 is still $200.

Comment: Sorry about that, you can do this with a sub query. I will update my post.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
SELECT p.ID, (p.[Product $] / c.CNT ) as [Result]
(
    SELECT ID,sum([Product $]) as [Product $]
    FROM [table]
    group by ID
) p inner join
(
    SELECT ID,count(1) as CNT
    FROM [table]
    group by ID
) c on (p.ID = c.ID)
```